# Finding Process That is Creating a File on Disk (After The Fact)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

In a Windows environment, how can I find a process that created a file, after the file was created. Or, how can I implement a solution that will track which process created a file, so that when the file is created that we can then make the determination of how it was created.

Finding the process that is creating a file **while** the file is being created is easy using something like ProcessMonitor (from SysInternals/Microsoft). However, we're looking at an environment where each PC has a file named "C:\temp\temp.txt" that just contains a zero on it. After deleting the file, it will, at some point, have the file recreated. Correlating the file creation time to events in Event Viewer has not yielded any results, and since the creation of the file isn't predictable I can't use something like ProcessMonitor to track it.

Optimally, since these machines are remote (managed under an RMM), I'd like something I can implement purely by command line.

Comment: Only way I can see is using process monitor to create a log over time, it will a be huge  log but you should be able to search for the file name in the log and find the process.

Comment: You can filter the log for only that file. It will appear blank until activity hits that file.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was hoping to not have to do that, but it seems it is my only option. I have it running and assuming the buffer doesn't crash the PC in the interim, I'll get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think what Shawn meant to put was* [**File Activity Watch**](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_activity_watch.html) by **NirSoft**.    Check it out and thanks to OP and Shawn, *I needed to find that.*

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't a perfect solution, you could use [FolderChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html) from Nirsoft to watch the Temp folder and trigger a process list or `handle` when the file is created.

Comment: Unfortunately, that shows the owner and time created, but not my primary criteria: what process created it.

Comment: @Beems So you tried it? a zero-length temp.txt file was created by the rogue app while you were testing and you used `handle` like `handle c:\temp\temp.txt`? Or are you assuming it isn't going to work because it's not showing locked in programs that don't lock it, like notepad or notepad++?